# Get Databricks Hive metastore connection username and password

Tags: azure, databricks, hive-metastore

I configured a Databricks cluster (Azure) and wonder how do we get access directly to the Hive metastore. This is what I did:

```
cat /databricks/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>[REDACTED]</value>
  <description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
```

The value is always has `[REDACTED]`
Is there a way to get clear text?

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I assume `dbutils.secrets.get()` can get the value if passing some specific params?

Comment: One way to reveal the value of the secret is to use value = dbutils.secrets.get('scope','key') and then value.split('#'), assuming you store some special character or unique character at the end or as a separator.

Comment: @VigneshG Thanks. Do you know how to find the hive metastore (default) scope name?

Comment: @HP.I am trying to connect to the databricks hive-metastore from my standalone spark, were you trying the same? If yes, were you able to connect?

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to retrieve both username and password using your command via the web terminal.

To do so, you first have to go "Settings->Admin Console->Workspace Settings", and then under "Advanced" activate "Web Terminal".

[image: Web Terminal option]

After that (maybe you need to refresh your page), you can start your cluster, open a Notebook (or create an empty one), and you should be able to see "Terminal" in the options of the cluster selection box (top-left corner of the Notebook page):

[image]

Once you click "Terminal", it should open a web terminal, and if you execute your command there (`cat /databricks/hive/conf/hive-site.xml`) you will get username and password in clear form.

I tried executing the same command in a Python script using `subprocess`, and it was redacted, so something must act differently.